# How does Leland know so much in Pandorum?

Tags: movie, pandorum

In the 2009 sci-fi movie Pandorum the protagonists group encounters a character named Leland who has been awake on the ship for much longer than they have been. He relates much of the background story to the group, explaining about the fate of Earth and how Gallo took over and created the monsters they have been running from.

Given that Leland looks to be in his forties or fifties and as a member of the crew was probably in his twenties when the ship launched, he might have been awake for 30 years or so. The events he relates took place *centuries earlier*, some time after the flight crew at the time get the message from Earth but before Gallo puts himself back into hypersleep - which judging by the age difference between younger and older Gallo would be a period of twenty to thirty years.

So my question: is it ever explained how Leland knows so much about the history of these events, given that most of it occurred long before he was even awakened? It seems unlikely he could have uncovered all that information himself.

Comment: I'm gonna go with "*because the screenplay reads like it was written by a hyperactive toddler*"

Comment: I haven't seen the movie so I don't know if the answer makes sense, but the question addressed in the imdb FAQ [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1188729/faq#.2.1.12), it just says *'When Leland tells the story, he says "that's what some would say". It can be assumed that he heard it from other victims of Gallo.'*

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that imdb answer doesn't make sense because any of Gallo's original victims would have been dead centuries before Leland's time. I suppose it could be argued that it was folklore that had been passed down over generations that had eventually reached Leland, but seems unlikely given the small number of crew who are awakened and survive for any length of time. Sounds like there isn't an answer to this question other than "plot hole".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The related movie script:

> Leland:
>
> Oh, how the whole world cheered to the thunder of earth's mightiest
> creation-- Elysium. One small spark to ignite the heavens for the
> heroes to venture farther and farther than any of mankind's machines!
> And we slept. We slept a slumber so deep that no one had dared
> before...as three little Indians were left to mind the store.
>
> Three little Indians with the burden to bear. No more law. Nothing
> left to care. Just three little souls whose destiny had become undone
> because there was chop chop chop chop... then there was only one. One
> little Indian left.
>
> One little Indian left, alone with all his doom. He refuses to go to
> bed, so what does he do? He decides to stay up and play in his room.
> What nasty little games he would play with his slumbering prey. He was
> slayer, he was master. He was both God and the Devil! See, that's what
> some would say. He would grow to manhood, a self-proclaimed king.
> Master of his own vessel. Home to his own sin.
>
> **He just cast out all who had behaved.** Just exiled to the cargo hold to fend amongst themselves... and scavenge, feeding off their
> own. Evil grew. The king no longer wanted to play. So he returned to
> his bed of slumber. And while the king slept, a whole new world of
> evil grew... as we wept.
>
> -- [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Pandorum)

I suspect those who behaved are normal passengers who didn't suffer from Pandorum. Gallo exiled them to the cargo hold and made them kill each other.

Leland woke up at an early age than the rest of the remaining crew members who had been placed in hypersleep. He learned this brutal history by reading the drawings done by Gallo's victims on the ship's walls.